# Find out where a Symfony route is defined?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working with a project that uses the Sonata Page Bundle.

After grepping all of my php files and settings files for the name of a route, I eventually found that it was being stored in the database, in a table called page__page.

My question is this: **Is there an easy way to find out where a matched route is defined?** Using the "profiler token" link on Symfony's debugging toolbar, I am at least able to get the name of the route, which is somewhat helpful. Unfortunately, that's where the default functionality appears to end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of ways to create and register routes.

The more complex are the [CMF](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cmf/components/routing/dynamic.html) and the [custom loading](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html).

Symfony don't track which route is defined where and when. It only tracks the `compiler_class` used. You can display it by using

```
bin/console debug:router page__page
```